# GStreamer - v4l2 unavailable for gstreamer 0.1

Tags: linux, gstreamer

When I use the 1.0 version, v4l2 plugin seem to be recognized, but doesn't work, so I decided to try the older version.

```
gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

But the output says "no plugin v4l2". How to install it for this version ?

Comment: omg why 0.10 ? its really archaic

Comment: I second the comment above. 0.10 has been obsolete and unmantained for around 4 years now. You won't get bugfixes or much help for such an old version. Please go back to trying 1.0 and check why it doesn't work. GST_DEBUG logs might help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reason for using 0.10, do you have the "good" plugins installed?  v4l2sink is part of the "good" plugins.  In Ubunutu Linux, you would do something like

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```